# Ignorar elemento em JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json, for

Digamos que temos uma JSON com 2 elementos a seguir:

```
    exemplo: { 
    [{
    "arquivo": "Arquio 1",
    "size": "2340"
    }, {
    "arquivo": "Arquivo 2",
    "size": "0"
     }, {
     "arquivo": "arquivo 3",
     "size": "4329"
     }
```

> Uso for() do PHP para fazer uma lista dos arquivos.

Por exemplo:

```
    for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
    $arquivo = $json->exemplo[$i]->arquivo;
    $size = $json->exemplo[$i]->size;

    echo "Nome: ".$nome." - ".$size."<br />";
    }
```

O que eu quero fazer é ignorar arquivos da lista que esteja com size(tamanho) "0" e deixar só os  maior que 0 antes de passar pra for() do PHP.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso deve funcionar:

```
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
  $arquivo = $json->exemplo[$i]->arquivo;
  $size = $json->exemplo[$i]->size ;

  if ((int)$json->exemplo[$i]->size < 1) {
      unset($json->exemplo[$i]);

  } else {
      echo "Nome: ".$nome." - ".$size."<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta! Digamos assim: tipo pego se ter 3 resultados e esses 3 for com size 0, ai dentro da for() vai ficar em branco.  Tem como mudar isso pra não ficar em branco? ou retornar uma msg de erro caso todos os resultados for com size 0

Comment: É, se todos os elementos são inválidos, o array fica vazio. O Que você quer que ocorra nesse caso?

Comment: Olha um exemplo: http://goo.gl/1iVZBg veja que fica tudo em branco quando são todos vazios, e tipo se tudo for vazio, tem como retornar uma msg de erro?

Comment: Tem sim, após o for: if (count($json->exemplo)=0) {   echo "Nenhum arquivo";  }

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar.

Comment: Ajudou.. Obrigadão!